# How do I kill spiders?

Tags: middle-earth-shadow-of-mordor

The first hunting challenge is killing three spiders. I seem to have killed one earlier, no idea how that happened, I didn't even *see* the thing. But the second one I saw, i ran up to it, tried to smash it with my sword, tried to stand on it, did a dance all over it. But it refused to die.

What do I need to do in order to get this evil creature to die a quick death? None of my orc killing skills (or lack thereof) seems to do anything.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can kill spiders by either shooting them, or just stepping on them. You probably accidentally stepped on one earlier. Just run over a spider, and he'll die with a nice, satisfying crunch. (or you can shoot him with your bow, but that seems excessive, no?)

Comment: I'll try my dance of "I am terrible at stepping on a specific spot" again.

Comment: I found using focus to shoot them with the bow the easiest. Same with a couple of later hunting challenges.

Comment: @Eben "a couple of later hunting challenges"?  I think challenge 4 (Mordor Rats) is the only other one that you have the alternative to kill with a mere step.  Having stepped on multiple Graugs, I can attest they are unaffected.

Comment: Using focus with the bow was the "same with" portion